# "java.lang.NoSuchFielErorr: Factory" when trying to create a new XSSFWorkbook()

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-2007, export-to-excel, xssf

I am trying to export some excel file and I need that row limit that XSSF has over HSSF and the code gets stuck when a new XSSFWorkbook is being initalized.

List of dependecies I have :

- `poi-5.1.0`
- `poi-ooxml-5.1.0`
  also the other poi dependecies
- `xmlbeans-5.0.2`
- `ooxml-schemas-1.3`
- `commons.io-2.11.0`

It seems that the program does not like this line `(CTWorkbook)CTWorkbook.Factory.newInstance();`

Did anybody encounter this Factory issue ? Thanks

Comment: Using `apache poi 5` you cannot use any of the `ooxml-schemas` classes. You need using either `poi-ooxml-lite` or `poi-ooxml-full`. See  https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components.

Comment: Thanks a lot Axel ! It fixed my issues !